# Emulator is not showing any outptut

Tags: android

Hey I'm new to android development. I made a very simple app (just a button and text field) but emulator doesn't show any output. And after a while it gave this error

```
[2014-07-03 09:43:31 - Emulator] NAND: nand_dev_load_disk_state ftruncate failed: Invalid argument
[2014-07-03 09:43:31 - Emulator] savevm: unable to load section nand_dev
[2014-07-03 09:45:37 - Partyup] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'sync'!
```

Kindly tell me how can I get it to work?

Comment: Not a solution but I'd suggest using Genymotion instead.

Comment: Emulator in Windows or Mac? "Eclipse ADT" or "Android Studio"? Your question sounds like off-topic.

Comment: Windows and Eclipse ADT

Answer (score 0):

Open AVD Manager and go to the AVD that is failing to load. Highlight that AVD and choose the Start button. You should get a dialog box that allows you to choose to Wipe User Data and also uncheck **Launch from snapshot**. That should reduce the size of the saved disk cache, If this is your app you should check to see what your saving to disk.

If that doesnt help,

Close your eclipse and AVD both if needed create new AVD with different API and start again everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to `Restart the emulator`,do following:-

1. Select & Right Click on Android Project
2. Run Configurations
3. Go to tab Target
4. Enable option Wipe User Data on Emulator launch parameters
5. Run Application

Also **reset adb** may help you,so reset your `adb` by doing following steps:-

1. Go to "DDMS" environment
2. open "Devices" tab and
3. in that top right corner you have "view menu"
4. click on it
5. you will get an option called "**reset adb**" just do that.